# Why are my OpenGL objects drawing relative to the last object drawn?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glfw

I'm pretty sure this is due to my lack of understanding of how the `GL_MODELVIEW` matrix works. Here is a screen recording of what's happening: http://youtu.be/3F7FLkVI7kA

As you can see, the bottom-most triangle is the first triangle being drawn, and moves as I expect the other 2 triangles to move. The second triangle is moved and rotated relative to the first, and the third is moved and rotated relative to that combination.

What I want is for all three triangles to be stationary in 3D space, but spinning (like the first triangle).

Source:

```
// Main loop
do {
    // Clear Screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Update camera
    glfwGetCursorPos(window, &cursorX, &cursorY);
    cam.update(0.001f, (int)cursorX, (int)cursorY);

    // Reset Matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    // move camera
    glRotatef(cam.rotation.x, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(cam.rotation.y, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // translate modelview matrix to position of the camera - everything should now draw relative to camera position
    glTranslatef(-cam.position.x, cam.position.y, -cam.position.z);

    // Draw ground
    drawGroundGrid(-25.0f);
    drawSpinningTriangle(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);
    drawSpinningTriangle(3.14f, 3.0f, -6.0f);
    drawSpinningTriangle(-6.0f, 12.0f, -5.0f);

    // Swap buffers - back buffer is now front buffer to be rendered to next frame
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    calcFPS();

} while (!glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) && !glfwWindowShouldClose(window));// Main Loop End

[...]

void drawSpinningTriangle(float x, float y, float z) {
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    glRotatef(glfwGetTime() * 50.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    {
        // Red vertex
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // Yellow vertex
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

        // White vertex
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Make sure your depth buffer is set up and enabled.

Comment: That's done, but wouldn't that only affect z-culling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First using the matrix stack is deprecated. It's much better to manage your own matrices

Second you should pushMatrix and popMatrix before the transformations and after drawing:

```
void drawSpinningTriangle(float x, float y, float z) {
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    glRotatef(glfwGetTime() * 50.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    {
        // Red vertex
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // Yellow vertex
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

        // White vertex
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    }
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();

}
```

This will save and restore the top most matrix so any changes between the 2 calls are removed.

Comment: What do you mean by managing your own matrices? Is that pushing and popping matrices?

Comment: @AlexMohr: No. Pushing and poping the matrices uses the old, deprecated OpenGL fixed function matrix stack. No serious program ever used that functionality; it's cumbersome to work with and offers zero benefits. So it got removed from modern OpenGL – good riddance. Anyway, what you should go is getting a real matrix math library (preferably one aimed for use in graphics, like GLM or linmath.h) and manage your own set of transformation matrices. You can still do hierarchical transformations, but you're far more flexible.